# defining bindings for elements in a collection in xaml wont work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

i have a simple Control with a collection of elements. I want to **add elements in xaml** and **bind to the element**.

However when i bind to Bar.Value in xaml it never works. Minimal example:

```cs
[ContentProperty("Bars")]
public class FooControl : Control
{
    private ObservableCollection<IBar> _bars = new ObservableCollection<IBar>();
    public ObservableCollection<IBar> Bars { get { return _bars; } }
}

public interface IBar
{
    string Value { get; }
}

public class Bar : DependencyObject, IBar
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(Bar), new PropertyMetadata("<not set>"));
    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="1000">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="this:FooControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="this:FooControl">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bars, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <sys:String>from DataContext</sys:String>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <this:FooControl>
            <this:Bar Value="directly set"/>
            <this:Bar Value="{Binding Source=from_binding_source}"/>
            <this:Bar Value="{Binding}"/>
            <this:Bar Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=SomeTextBlock}"/>
        </this:FooControl>
        <TextBlock Text="from TextBox" Name="SomeTextBlock" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

output

```
directly set
from_binding_source
"<not set>"
"<not set>"
```

debug output

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'Bar' (HashCode=26568931); target property is 'Value' (type 'String')

**Any suggestion how to get it to work?**

My current workaround is to define the bindings in code but this is a lot more code and looking at the xaml its not obvious which bindings do exists. (see my answer for workaround code)

Comment: can you post the code for your actual workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my workaround so far

```
    <this:Bar x:Name="bar3" />
    <this:Bar x:Name="bar4" />

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bar3 = (DependencyObject)FindName("bar3");
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(bar3, Bar.ValueProperty, new Binding("DataContext") { Source = this });

    var bar4 = (DependencyObject)FindName("bar4");
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(bar4, Bar.ValueProperty, new Binding("Text") { Source = FindName("SomeTextBlock") });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont know if this helps but

```
[ContentProperty("Bars")]
public class FooControl : Control
{
   private ObservableCollection<object> _bars = new ObservableCollection<object>();
   public ObservableCollection<object> Bars { get { return _bars; } }
}
```

xaml

```
  <this:FooControl>
        <this:Bar Value="directly set"/>
        <this:Bar Value="{Binding Source=from_binding_source}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=SomeTextBlock}"/>
    </this:FooControl>
```

you get your desired result

[image]

Comment: unfortunatly not. What i posted was a minimal example showing the problem. The code you posted abuses the fact that the ItemsControl checks for visual elements. IBar is really a plugin point which extends the capabilities of Foo and is not shown itself